# How to remove a list of words with nothing in notepad++ (or similar)

Tags: notepad++

Hi guys I'm not very good with regular expressions so I usually try to find an example of what I need to do, since it's a one time thing most of the times.

I would like to know, if I have a long list of words (like: "a", "I", "you", "with", "about", "but", "for", and so on and so forth), how would I go about removing all of them at once from a text.

Another problem is that with this syntax I found **(yahoo|candy|goku)**, it doesn't let me to match whole words (not sure at all why), so if I want to delete the word "a", it is also going to delete every instance of the letter "a". Which isn't the goal!

So, would there be any way of doing this? Do I need a more robus program maybe?

Thanks in advance, and just as some context I would like to point that I have several texts with thousands of words, and I need to filter them, so this is the way I THOUGHT would be easier, so far doesn't look as easy, since it seems I need to look and replace for each word individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before and after the list:

```
\b(a|I|you|with|about|but|for)\b
```

Comment: ok this has one caveat that is if the words ends in "a", it also deleted the last letter of the word, which is incoveniente. Working on it though

Comment: Ok it SEEMS like if I mess up the list, for example, i have more than one occurence of "a", or I have two || together, or the string ends in "|)\b" instead of ")\b", it behaves in unexpected ways. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

> ( a | I | you | with | about | but | for )

Don't forget the space betwenn `|` and the word. This will look for your words with space before and after.

You should maybe add other regex with a dot at the end (end of sentence without space) or without space in front (start a sentence)

Comment: oooooooh so the space is relevant. Goddamn. Ok that's great to know.

Comment: @keont Acutally I also just figured this out :)

Comment: @Toto As I said he should add different regex with word without the space before or after.

Answer (score -1):

Here regex which you can easy edit for your needs:
`( |")(a|I|you)( |\.|,|;|'|")` 
`( |")` - symbols before word, 
`(a|I|you)` - words to replace
`( |\.|,|;|'|")` - symbols after word